# Making an AI for a tile game

Tags: javascript, arrays, artificial-intelligence, cell

Im making a game involving a table of 'tiles' where the aim is to get them grouped into blocks of 2 by 2 of that colour with there being 16 unique colours. I have finished this part of the game and would like to move on to make an AI component that gives a suggestion for a minimum number of moves you can complete the game in.
Ive decided to use a 2d array so it recognizes where each colour is without directly affecting the board and I need a bit of help. once I finish the array what its should do is recognize the colour of the first tile and look for colours of that tile and swap them with the surrounding blocks to the right underneath and underneath and to the right. Can anyone help?

Comment: AI is a complicated topic. At a minimum read an introductory book or attend some uni course to get familiar with it.

Comment: Start coding, if you find you are unable to progress further at any point, feel free to come here again. If you are unable to start yourself, you should definitly not be doing this.

Comment: So, you'll need to create a function that generates all possible board states that can be moved to in a single move from a particular board state. You'll need to be able to score your board states (or at least be able to detect a finishing state). Then you'll need to implement a breadth-first search to find the board state that is closest to your current board state. You may also want to consider adding a heuristic measure to guide your search in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking to do is solve a simpler problem which shouldn't require AI, per se.  Your best bet is to create an array for each attempted solution-- possibly in a 2-dimensional array itself-- and solve each puzzle several times keeping track of the moves.  The array of arrays will act as a list to make sure you get unique solutions.

You will probably want to implement a recursive solving algorithm to fill each array, have an upper limit to either the number of attempts or time to solve (or both) and provide the solution with the lowest number of turns as the hint.

You may not end up with the absolute minimum number of turns mathematically possible but it's at least a starting point (and with some further research into the math and algorithm optimization you may hit upon the perfect mathematical solution).  That and it's a game, so have fun with it ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how the game work,  I assume that the way it works is to swap colors between adjacent blocks until the completion condition is reached.

If want you want is to find the best solution, you should do something like this:

```
FUNCTION SEARCH(StackOfMoves I,O)
   FOR EACH position in chekcboard
       FOR EACH direction in possibleMoves
          makeMove(position , direction)
          StackOfMoves->addMoveToStack(position, direction)
          IF GameCompleted()
              RETURN StackOfMoves
          ELSE 
              SEARCH(StackOfMoves)
          END IF
       END FOR
   END FOR

   RETURN StackOfMoves
END FUNCTION
```

**EDIT**

Analyzed it quietly and I think it wouldn´t work properly unless you set a limit of iterations or conditional exit, if it chooses a bad moveit could keep iterating over bad moves over and over. A conditional to see if the current state has already been processed and returning false if not might fix it, but may be a better solution, for sure. I will try to give a better answer later.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you will probably want a variation of depth-first search for this. This essentially makes a move, assigns a score to the new position, and either backtracks to the previous position or makes another move. The possible sequences of moves in the game can be represented as a tree, and depth-first starts at the root of the tree and evaluates moves until it reaches a leaf node (or a maximum depth) and then backtracks one node and evaluates the next sibling branch. This can be done iteratively or recursively.

Computing a score for each board position is important for any kind of search. You need to know if any position is better or worse than other positions. Your scoring algorithm really depends on the game. In games where you capture pieces such as chess, a very basic scoring algorithm would just assign a point value to each piece. Your score for each position is just the sum of your pieces minus the sum of the enemy pieces. You would have to come up with a scoring algorithm for your own game. Ideally this will be fast to calculate and will give a better score as you get close to winning.

Scores for each position can be stored in a database, so that if the same position can be reached with different sequences of moves, you only have to compute the score for that position once. Then if you reach that same position again in your search you already have the score in the database. Programs typically calculate a hash of the board state to index the positions in the table.

With depth-first, the amount of calculation required depends partly on the depth of the search. A number of chess programs use a technique called iterative deepening to allow a search to generate a guess quickly and then generate better moves after more search time. You search first with a depth of 1 move. Each of these positions is stored in the database so you need not recalculate scores. Once you evaluate all moves to depth of 1, you start over and evaluate move trees to depth 2. Each iteration requires exponentially more time to calculate, so iterative deepening allows you to generate better moves as you have more time to think.

With a depth-first search and database of scores, you can do branch pruning. If as you descend a branch, you determine that your best possible score for that branch is worse than a branch you have already evaluated, then you can stop the current branch and backtrack. This is usually done with two player games where each player is trying to maximize his own score and minimize the opponent's score. Search for alpha-beta pruning for more about this.

Depth-first search is just one algorithm you could use. Depending on the game you could have better results with other kinds of algorithms. You could use a neural network for example, and it might replace search time during a game with training time prior to the game. Regardless, you can spend a lot of time developing an AI, even for seemingly simple games.